# Access members of record

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

According to the documentation for [`each()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE), it returns `setof(key text, value text)`. However, when using it from a `SELECT`, I can't seem to access `key` or `value`. I've tried searching for information on `record` types but all I can find is some unhelpful bit related to [plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS).

Say I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  data HSTORE NOT NULL
);
```

And I run the query:

```sql
SELECT pair
FROM (
  SELECT each(data) AS pair
  FROM mytable
) AS pairs
```

I get rows of the `record` type:

```
(key1,value1)
(key2,value2)
...
```

If I try accessing the `key` or `value`, I get various errors.

1. This:

   ```
    SELECT pair.key, pair.value
    FROM (
      SELECT each(data) AS pair
      FROM mytable
    ) AS pairs
   ```

   Gives:

   ```
    ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "pair"
    LINE 1:  pair.key,
             ^
    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "pair"
    SQL state: 42P01
    Character: 8
   ```
2. This:

   ```
    SELECT pair.key, pair.value
    FROM (
      SELECT each(data) AS pair (key, value)
      FROM mytable
    ) AS pairs
   ```

   Gives:

   ```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
    LINE 4:   each(data) AS pair (key, value)
                                 ^

    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
    SQL state: 42601
    Character: 71
   ```
3. This:

   ```
    SELECT pairs.pair.key, pairs.pair.value
    FROM (
      SELECT each(data) AS pair
      FROM mytable
    ) AS pairs
   ```

   Gives:

   ```
    ERROR:  schema "pairs" does not exist

    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: schema "pairs" does not exist
    SQL state: 3F000
   ```
4. This:

   ```
    SELECT pair[1], pair[2]
    FROM (
      SELECT each(data) AS pair
      FROM mytable
    ) AS pairs
   ```

   Gives:

   ```
    ERROR:  cannot subscript type record because it is not an array

    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: cannot subscript type record because it is not an array
    SQL state: 42804
   ```

How do I properly access the members of a `record` type in PostgreSQL?

Comment: `each` is for `hstore`, not `record`.

Comment: @CraigRinger `each(hstore)` returns `setof record`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 9.3, use `LATERAL`.

```
regress=> SELECT p.key, p.value FROM mytable, LATERAL each(data) p;
 key | value 
-----+-------
 a   | b
 c   | d
(2 rows)
```

In older versions, you must use wildcard expansion, which is a bit ugly.

```
regress=> SELECT (pair).*                                
FROM (
  SELECT each(data) AS pair
  FROM mytable
) AS pairs
;
 key | value 
-----+-------
 a   | b
 c   | d
(2 rows)
```

---

Side note:

`each` returns a typed result set with `OUT` parameters, so the return type and column names are known. It returns a set, i.e. it may return multiple rows for a single invocation:

```
regress=> \df each
                                  List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type |           Argument data types           |  Type  
--------+------+------------------+-----------------------------------------+--------
 public | each | SETOF record     | hs hstore, OUT key text, OUT value text | normal
(1 row)
```

I mention this because a function that returns `record` or `setof record` *without* typed `OUT` parameters can't be used the way I've shown above, you have to provide a special format param-list for such functions.